# Optimizing SQL-Query using CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, common-table-expression

I have written the following (simplified) query:

```sql
;WITH 
PreAggregated AS
(
    --Group by including ClassId and MeasureId
    SELECT    
                [ColumnA],[ColumnB],[ColumnC],[ClassId],[MeasureId]                                                 
                , SUM(a.[NonAggregatedValues]) as PreAggregatedValues                                          
    FROM  [TableA] a
                INNER JOIN [TableB] b on b.PrimaryKey = a.ForeignKey1
                INNER JOIN [TableC] c on c.PrimaryKey = a.ForeignKey2
    WHERE a.ReportDate = @reportDate AND c.TechID IN ([...])
    GROUP BY 
                [ColumnA],[ColumnB],[ColumnC],[ClassId],[MeasureId]
),
AllCombinations AS
(
    --No values aggregated, just gets all possible combinations and is then left joined to [A],[B],[C],...
    SELECT [ColumnA],[ColumnB],[ColumnC] FROM PreAggregated a
    WHERE TechID IN ([...]) AND ReportDate = @reportDate
    GROUP BY [ColumnA],[ColumnB],[ColumnC]
),
A AS
(
    --Pivot for all ClassId = 5 using MeasureId 1-3
    SELECT [ColumnA],[ColumnB],[ColumnC],SUM([1]) [1],SUM([2]) [2],SUM([3]) [3]
    FROM (
                SELECT [ColumnA],[ColumnB],[ColumnC],[ClassId],[MeasureId] 
                FROM   PreAggregated
                WHERE [ClassId] = 5 AND TechID IN ([...]) AND ReportDate = @reportDate) as [DATA]  
                PIVOT(
                           Sum([PreAggregatedValues])
                           FOR MeasureId IN ([1],[2],[3])) AS PIVOT_DATA
    GROUP BY [...]
),
B AS
(
    --Pivot for all ClassId = 6 using MeasureId 1-3
    SELECT [ColumnA],[ColumnB],[ColumnC],SUM([1]) [1],SUM([2]) [2],SUM([3]) [3]
    FROM (
                SELECT [...] 
                FROM   PreAggregated
                WHERE [ClassId] = 6 AND TechID IN ([...]) AND ReportDate = @reportDate) as [DATA]  
                PIVOT(
                           Sum([PreAggregatedValues])
                           FOR MeasureId IN ([1],[2],[3])) AS PIVOT_DATA
    GROUP BY [...]
),
C AS
(
    --Pivot for all ClassId = 7 using MeasureId 1-3
    [...]
)

SELECT                       
        AllCombinations.[x],
        AllCombinations.[y],
        [...],
        A.[1] [A_1],
        A.[2] [A_2],
        A.[3] [A_3],
        B.[1] [B_1],
        B.[2] [B_2],
        B.[3] [B_3],
        C.[1] [C_1],
        C.[2] [C_2],
        C.[3] [C_3],
        [...]
FROM
    AllCombinations 
    LEFT JOIN A ON AllCombinations.TechID = A.TechID
    LEFT JOIN B ON AllCombinations.TechID = B.TechID
    LEFT JOIN C ON AllCombinations.TechID = C.TechID
    [...]
```

I  feel this is by far not the best way to carry out the query. I´ve been trying out a lot of options and this is the most performant design I´ve come up with. Also, of course I´ve been using indexes, but it´s about the query design here.

Is there a way to optimize this? In particular:

- The pivotised sections [A][B][C],... (in total up to 7) are nearly identical and just differ by the ClassId filter. Can I merge those queries somehow?
- Is a common table expression the best way to handle this?

**UPDATE:**

Here´s the complete, alienated query:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Complete_Pivot]
(           
            @RDate DATETIME,
            @pid INT
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
            WITH 
            PIDs AS
            (
                        SELECT PID, PPID  FROM PTree a WHERE a.RDate = @RDate AND a.PID = @pid AND a.PID NOT IN (9359,9360,9361)
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT child.PID, child.PPID FROM PTree child INNER JOIN PIDs parent ON child.PPID = parent.PID WHERE child.RDate = @RDate AND child.PID NOT IN (9359,9360,9361)
            ),
            PreAggregated AS
            (
                        SELECT    
                                    se.[RDate]
                                    , rf.[RCID]
                                    , rf.[RMID]
                                    , de.[PID]
                                    , de.[PCID]
                                    , de.[DID]
                                    , de.INSID
                                    , de.INTID
                                    , de.[DDID]
                                    , de.[LID]
                                    , de.[LT]
                                    , de.[RC]                                                                      
                                    , SUM(se.[SVal]) as PreAggregatedValues                                           
                        FROM  [TableS] se
                                    INNER JOIN [TableRF] rf on rf.RFID = se.RFID
                                    INNER JOIN [TableD] de on de.DID = se.DID
                        WHERE se.RDate = @RDate AND de.PID IN (SELECT PID FROM PIDs)
                        GROUP BY 
                                    se.[RDate]
                                    , rf.[RCID]
                                    , rf.[RMID]
                                    , de.[PID]
                                    , de.[PCID]
                                    , de.[DID]
                                    , de.INSID
                                    , de.INTID
                                    , de.[DDID]
                                    , de.[LID]
                                    , de.[LT]
                                    , de.[RC]
            ),
            AllCombinations AS
            (
                        SELECT DID, [DDID], [PID],  [INSID], INTID, [LID],[LT],[RC],[RDate] FROM PreAggregated 
                        WHERE PID IN (SELECT PID FROM PIDs) AND RDate = @RDate
                        GROUP BY DID, [DDID],[PID],  [INSID], INTID, [LID],[LT],[RC],[RDate]
            ),
            [A] AS
            (
                        SELECT DID, [DDID],[PID],  [INSID], INTID, [LID],[LT],[RC],[RDate],SUM([1]) [1],SUM([2]) [2],SUM([3]) [3]
                        FROM (
                                    SELECT RMID, DID, [DDID],[PID],  [INSID], INTID, [LID],[LT],[RC],[RDate],[PreAggregatedValues] 
                                    FROM   PreAggregated
                                    WHERE RCID = 5 AND PID IN (SELECT PID FROM PIDs) AND RDate = @RDate) as DATA   
                                    PIVOT(
                                               Sum(PreAggregatedValues)
                                               FOR RMID IN ([1],[2],[3])) AS PIVOT
                        GROUP BY DID, [DDID],[PID],  [INSID], INTID, [LID],[LT],[RC],[RDate]
            ),
            [B] AS
            (
                        SELECT DID, [DDID],[PID],  [INSID], INTID, [LID],[LT],[RC],[RDate],SUM([1]) [1],SUM([2]) [2],SUM([3]) [3]
                        FROM (
                                    SELECT RMID, DID, [DDID],[PID],  [INSID], INTID, [LID],[LT],[RC],[RDate],[PreAggregatedValues] 
                                    FROM   PreAggregated
                                    WHERE RCID = 6 AND PID IN (SELECT PID FROM PIDs) AND RDate = @RDate) as DATA   
                                    PIVOT(
                                               Sum(PreAggregatedValues)
                                               FOR RMID IN ([1],[2],[3])) AS PIVOT
                        GROUP BY DID, [DDID],[PID],  [INSID], INTID, [LID],[LT],[RC],[RDate]
            ),
            [C] AS
            (
                        SELECT DID, [DDID],[PID],  [INSID], INTID, [LID],[LT],[RC],[RDate],SUM([1]) [1],SUM([2]) [2],SUM([3]) [3]
                        FROM (
                                    SELECT RMID, DID, [DDID],[PID],  [INSID], INTID, [LID],[LT],[RC],[RDate],[PreAggregatedValues] 
                                    FROM   PreAggregated
                                    WHERE RCID = 7 AND PID IN (SELECT PID FROM PIDs) AND RDate = @RDate) as DATA   
                                    PIVOT(
                                               Sum(PreAggregatedValues)
                                               FOR RMID IN ([1],[2],[3])) AS PIVOT
                        GROUP BY DID, [DDID],[PID],  [INSID], INTID, [LID],[LT],[RC],[RDate]
            ),
            [D] AS
            (
                        SELECT DID, [DDID],[PID],  [INSID], INTID, [LID],[LT],[RC],[RDate],SUM([1]) [1],SUM([2]) [2],SUM([3]) [3]
                        FROM (
                                    SELECT RMID, DID, [DDID],[PID],  [INSID], INTID, [LID],[LT],[RC],[RDate],[PreAggregatedValues] 
                                    FROM   PreAggregated
                                    WHERE RCID = 8 AND PID IN (SELECT PID FROM PIDs) AND RDate = @RDate) as DATA   
                                    PIVOT(
                                               Sum(PreAggregatedValues)
                                               FOR RMID IN ([1],[2],[3])) AS PIVOT
                        GROUP BY DID, [DDID],[PID],  [INSID], INTID, [LID],[LT],[RC],[RDate]
            ),
            [E] AS
            (
                        SELECT DID, [DDID],[PID],  [INSID], INTID, [LID],[LT],[RC],[RDate],SUM([1]) [1],SUM([2]) [2],SUM([3]) [3]
                        FROM (
                                    SELECT RMID, DID, [DDID],[PID],  [INSID], INTID, [LID],[LT],[RC],[RDate],[PreAggregatedValues] 
                                    FROM   PreAggregated
                                    WHERE RCID = 9 AND PID IN (SELECT PID FROM PIDs) AND RDate = @RDate) as DATA   
                                    PIVOT(
                                               Sum(PreAggregatedValues)
                                               FOR RMID IN ([1],[2],[3])) AS PIVOT
                        GROUP BY DID, [DDID],[PID],  [INSID], INTID, [LID],[LT],[RC],[RDate]
            )

            SELECT 
                        AllCombinations.[RDate],
                        AllCombinations.PID,
                        AllCombinations.[DID],
                        
                        AllCombinations.[INSID],
                        AllCombinations.INTID,

                        AllCombinations.[DDID],

                        AllCombinations.[LID],
                        AllCombinations.[LT],
                        AllCombinations.[RC],
                        
                        A.[1] [A_1],
                        A.[2] [A_2],
                        A.[3] [A_3],
                        B.[1] [B_1],
                        B.[2] [B_2],
                        B.[3] [B_3],
                        C.[1] [C_1],
                        C.[2] [C_2],
                        C.[3] [C_3],
                        D.[1] [D_1],
                        D.[2] [D_2],
                        D.[3] [D_3],
                        E.[1] [E_1],
                        E.[2] [E_2],
                        E.[3] [E_3],
            FROM
                        AllCombinations 
                        LEFT JOIN A ON AllCombinations.DID = A.DID
                        LEFT JOIN B ON AllCombinations.DID = B.DID
                        LEFT JOIN C ON AllCombinations.DID = C.DID
                        LEFT JOIN D ON AllCombinations.DID = D.DID
                        LEFT JOIN E ON AllCombinations.DID = E.DID
)
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Find the query plan here: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1KBQOkgi

Comment: You want us to help you optimise this, however, you omit huge parts of the query. I would suggest, as a start, you provide the query plan via Paste the Plan, and then we see where we go from there... But I suspect that you are asking a lot of the user base here. Honsetly, the problem looks overly complicated; perhaps you would be better off asking a (different) question asking how to achieve what you want to do, rather than how to optimised what my be an inherently poor way way to achieve it.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for taking a look at the query. I´ve updated my question with the complate query now and will be updating again to show what I´m trying to achieve. Sorry, query is a bit hard to read, especially when alienated, you´re right.

Comment: What about that query plan, @Chris ?

Comment: One thing at a time :-) It takes time to alienate

Comment: @Larnu Do you want me to post the query plan as xml via paste the plan?

Comment: You simply need to include the link to the plan on [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) in the question.

Comment: @Larnu Ok, Ive updated again with the link to PasteThePlan

Comment: Honestly, I stand by my original statement: *"you would be better off asking a (different) question asking how to achieve what you want to do, rather than how to optimise what may be an inherently poor way to achieve it."* That query plan is real messy. Without understanding the goal, then I doubt we have a good way to tell you how to approach the problem differently.

Comment: @Larnu I know it is - hence the question :-) Ok, I´ll give it another try with example tables and what I´m trying to achieve

Comment: Posting the actual execution plan instead of an estimated plan is almost always better. Also, you really should post table definitions and some sample data for those tables so others can run the query themselves. Otherwise anybody else is just guessing what may or may not work.

Comment: Already have to optimized this kind of query. You can use temporary tables (in a stored procedure), or table variables if you need to use specifically a function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#c-declaring-a-variable-of-type-table).

Comment: You can also have a minor improvement by updating the 'PID IN (SELECT PID FROM PIDs)' clause in EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PIDs loc WHERE xxx.PID = loc.PID)

Comment: @RomEh Thanks for commenting! I will try this out on Monday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some improvements can be made to your request:

- Make use of [variable tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#c-declaring-a-variable-of-type-table) if the function is required, or temporary table if you can switch to a stored procedure, to split cascaded CTEs,
- Avoid extra filters, if data is already filtered,
- Avoid the pattern `<field> IN (SELECT <field> FROM <table>)`. Replace by `INNER JOIN` clauses or at least by `EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM <table> al WHERE al.<field> = a2.<field>)`
- In temporary tables only keep used fields

There is a first attempt to optimize your function code:

```
DECLARE @selectedPids TABLE
(
    PID bigint NOT NULL,
    RDate datetime NOT NULL
);

WITH recursivePID AS
(
    SELECT  PID,
            PPID
    FROM PTree a
    WHERE a.RDate = @RDate AND a.PID = @pid AND a.PID NOT IN (9359,9360,9361)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT child.PID, child.PPID
    FROM PTree child
            INNER JOIN recursivePID parent ON child.PPID = parent.PID
    WHERE child.RDate = @RDate AND child.PID NOT IN (9359,9360,9361)
)
INSERT INTO @selectedPids
SELECT  PID,
        @RDate
FROM recursivePID
GROUP BY PID;

DECLARE @aggregatedPids TABLE
(
    RDate   datetime NOT NULL,
    RCID    bigint,
    RMID    bigint,
    PID     bigint,
    PCID    bigint,
    DID     bigint,
    INSID   bigint,
    INTID   bigint,
    DDID    bigint,
    LID     bigint,
    LT      varchar(50),
    RC      varchar(50),
    PreAggregatedValues bigint
);

SELECT  se.[RDate]
        , rf.[RCID]
        , rf.[RMID]
        , de.[PID]
        , de.[PCID]
        , de.[DID]
        , de.INSID
        , de.INTID
        , de.[DDID]
        , de.[LID]
        , de.[LT]
        , de.[RC]                                                                      
        , SUM(se.[SVal]) as PreAggregatedValues                                           
FROM  @selectedPids pi
        INNER JOIN [TableD] de ON pi.PID = de.PID
        INNER JOIN [TableS] se ON de.DID = se.DID AND pi.RDate = se.RDate -- index on DID AND RDate
        INNER JOIN [TableRF] rf on se.RFID = rf.RFID
GROUP BY se.[RDate], rf.[RCID], rf.[RMID], de.[PID], de.[PCID], de.[DID], de.INSID, de.INTID, de.[DDID], de.[LID], de.[LT], de.[RC];

DECLARE @combinedPids TABLE
(
    DID     bigint,
    DDID    bigint,
    PID     bigint,
    INSID   bigint,
    INTID   bigint,
    LID     bigint,
    LT      varchar(50),
    RC      varchar(50),
    RDate   datetime NOT NULL
);

-- PID and Rdate were already filtered in above queries
INSERT INTO @combinedPids
SELECT DID, [DDID], [PID],  [INSID], INTID, [LID],[LT],[RC],[RDate]
FROM @aggregatedPids ap
WHERE ESISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @selectedPids sp WHERE sp.PID = ap.PID) PID IN (SELECT PID FROM PIDs) AND RDate = @RDate
GROUP BY DID, [DDID],[PID],  [INSID], INTID, [LID],[LT],[RC],[RDate];

DECLARE @pivoted TABLE
(
    Class       varchar(1) NOT NULL,
    DID         bigint,
    DDID        bigint,
    PID         bigint,
    INSID       bigint,
    INTID       bigint,
    LID         bigint,
    LT          varchar(50),
    RC          varchar(50),
    RDate       datetime NOT NULL,
    Aggregated1 bigint,
    Aggregated2 bigint,
    Aggregated3 bigint
);

-- Create a sub function to factorize code.
INSERT INTO @pivoted
SELECT 'A', DID, [DDID],[PID],  [INSID], INTID, [LID],[LT],[RC],[RDate],SUM([1]) [1],SUM([2]) [2],SUM([3]) [3]
FROM    (
            SELECT RMID, DID, [DDID],[PID],  [INSID], INTID, [LID],[LT],[RC],[RDate],[PreAggregatedValues] 
            FROM   @aggregatedPids
            WHERE RCID = 5 --AND PID IN (SELECT PID FROM PIDs) AND RDate = @RDate >> already filtered
        ) as DATA
        PIVOT(
            SUM(PreAggregatedValues)
            FOR RMID IN ([1],[2],[3])
        ) AS PIVOT
GROUP BY DID, [DDID],[PID], [INSID], INTID, [LID],[LT],[RC],[RDate];

INSERT INTO @pivoted
SELECT 'B', DID, [DDID],[PID],  [INSID], INTID, [LID],[LT],[RC],[RDate],SUM([1]) [1],SUM([2]) [2],SUM([3]) [3]
FROM    (
            SELECT RMID, DID, [DDID],[PID],  [INSID], INTID, [LID],[LT],[RC],[RDate],[PreAggregatedValues] 
            FROM   @aggregatedPids
            WHERE RCID = 6 --AND PID IN (SELECT PID FROM PIDs) AND RDate = @RDate >> already filtered
        ) as DATA
        PIVOT(
            SUM(PreAggregatedValues)
            FOR RMID IN ([1],[2],[3])
        ) AS PIVOT
GROUP BY DID, [DDID],[PID], [INSID], INTID, [LID],[LT],[RC],[RDate];

-- ... complete over pivot ...

INSERT INTO @pivoted
SELECT 'E', DID, [DDID],[PID],  [INSID], INTID, [LID],[LT],[RC],[RDate],SUM([1]) [1],SUM([2]) [2],SUM([3]) [3]
FROM    (
            SELECT RMID, DID, [DDID],[PID],  [INSID], INTID, [LID],[LT],[RC],[RDate],[PreAggregatedValues] 
            FROM   @aggregatedPids
            WHERE RCID = 9 --AND PID IN (SELECT PID FROM PIDs) AND RDate = @RDate >> already filtered
        ) as DATA
        PIVOT(
            SUM(PreAggregatedValues)
            FOR RMID IN ([1],[2],[3])
        ) AS PIVOT
GROUP BY DID, [DDID],[PID], [INSID], INTID, [LID],[LT],[RC],[RDate];

SELECT  cp.[RDate],
        cp.PID,
        cp.[DID],
                        
        cp.[INSID],
        cp.INTID,

        cp.[DDID],

        cp.[LID],
        cp.[LT],
        cp.[RC],
                        
        A.[Aggregated1] [A_1],
        A.[Aggregated2] [A_2],
        A.[Aggregated3] [A_3],
        B.[Aggregated1] [B_1],
        B.[Aggregated2] [B_2],
        B.[Aggregated3] [B_3],
        C.[Aggregated1] [C_1],
        C.[Aggregated2] [C_2],
        C.[Aggregated3] [C_3],
        D.[Aggregated1] [D_1],
        D.[Aggregated2] [D_2],
        D.[Aggregated3] [D_3],
        E.[Aggregated1] [E_1],
        E.[Aggregated2] [E_2],
        E.[Aggregated3] [E_3],
FROM    @combinedPids cp 
        LEFT JOIN @pivoted A ON cp.DID = A.DID
        LEFT JOIN @pivoted B ON cp.DID = B.DID
        LEFT JOIN @pivoted C ON cp.DID = C.DID
        LEFT JOIN @pivoted D ON cp.DID = D.DID
        LEFT JOIN @pivoted E ON cp.DID = E.DID;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for having an extensive look at the query. I will try out on Monday!

Comment: I had a go using your attempt and it gave me a few ideas. In the end it was a mixture of using a table variable for the recursive query and a cte for the rest. That speeded up the query from 4mins to 16secs. Thanks a lot, I appreciate your help!